# Running XCTests written for framework on device

Tags: ios, ios7, xctest

I want to run `XCTests` on a device which is written for framework project. `XCTests` allows you to run on a device for an application, but if I also try it for a framework,it shows an error:

> Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported. You can run logic tests on the Simulator.

I saw other posts mentioning the same but they were related to application projects. With latest `XCTests` you can easily run your unit test cases written for a application on a device, but it's not allowed in a framework/library project.

Is there any way to make it run on a device? I am using some frameworks within project which are not available for simulator. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to test on device?

Comment: Because I have used motion related API's, which are not available for simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Create a simple app that does nothing but link in your framework. Use it as your test host.

Comment: Are you saying I can run the test cases within framework via this test host app? Or you are suggesting to use this app as a simple test app to use framework API's?

Comment: The former. All you need is an app that contains the code you want to exercise. The app doesn't need to do anything else.